# Image inside div container has a 5px gap at the bottom

Tags: html, css

If you go to my Website that i am working on:

http://lastdeath.de/kaufmannmike/wallpaper.html

You can see 2 images (`img`) both inside 2 different `div` elements.
Something is weird there. The images have 5 bottom pixels, even if I
don't set it anyways. I've just put an `img` element in a `class="content"` and then in `div id="breaker/boxer"` , nothing really complicated.

But the code just don't want to work.

i can make a line code of an `img`, then there are no problems with these 5 pixels on the bottom. But i need to put the `img` in a `div` container.

**Code:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div max-height="480px" id="breaker">
    <img src="http://lastdeath.de/kaufmannmike/img/2_work/wallpaper/breaker-wallpaper_long.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="boxer">
    <img src="http://lastdeath.de/kaufmannmike/img/2_work/wallpaper/boxer-wallpaper_long.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set your `img` to `display:block`

why? because default value of `img` is `display:inline`

so instead of this:

```css
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

you should have this:

```css
img {
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a working snippet based on your code taken from your site:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
img {
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div max-height="480px" id="breaker">
    <img src="http://lastdeath.de/kaufmannmike/img/2_work/wallpaper/breaker-wallpaper_long.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="boxer">
    <img src="http://lastdeath.de/kaufmannmike/img/2_work/wallpaper/boxer-wallpaper_long.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```